# How to set shadow all sides in cardview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I want to add shadow in all side of the cardview like this, can anbody help?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [article](https://medium.com/@ArmanSo/take-control-of-views-shadow-android-c6b35ba573e9) can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    app:cardElevation="20dp"/>
```